# Test promise chain angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine

How do you mock the second call to then in this code in an angular service.

```
 myService.promise.then(function () {
            userConfig = userService.getUserConfiguration();
        }).then(function () {
         //do more stuff
        })
```

I know that I can mock the first call as follows:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    spyOn(myService.promise, 'then').and.returnValue({$promise: deferred.promise});
    deferred.resolve();
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're returning `deferred.promise` using your first spy, you can just spy on `deferred.promise.then` to create your second spy.

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't see that you had it wrapped in an object. You can assign that object to a variable and return that. Then you can reference the object's properties for your spy and do something like `spyOn(returnObject.$promise, 'then')`, assuming the variable name returnObject.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($q) {
    var deferred_1 = $q.defer();
    var return_1 = {$promise: deferred_1.promise};
    var deferred_2 = $q.defer();
    var return_2 = {$promise: deferred_2.promise};
    spyOn(myService.promise, 'then').and.returnValue(return_1);
    spyOn(return_1.$promise, 'then').and.returnValue(return_2);
    deferred.resolve();
}));
```

Comment: So there isn't a way to test it ?

Comment: No, I was saying that you CAN test it. Sorry if it was confusing wording. =)

You can spy on it and I've edited the answer to maybe help clarify things.

Comment: Thanks for the example: at the moment with this i get the same error:
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (near '...}).then(function () {...')